# How do ACID Transactions with Nodejs + Tokumx (mongodb) + any Mongodb driver for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, tokumx

Do you know any TokuMX driver for nodejs for doing ACID Transactions?

I would like to use the Databaseengine TOKUMX, wich is kind of a fork of MongoDB, and uses the same API like mongo, but has some built in improvements namely it uses real ACID Transactions. MongoDB in its native form does not allow ACID. But TOKUMX does.

So, I do write my APPs in Nodejs. For the necessary driver to communicate with TokuMX Database  I use **node-mongolian**. The good news is I can send all the commands to the database using that driver. For example:

in nodeJS code:

```
mycollectionblabla.runCommand('beginTransaction', function(err, res) { ....
mycollectionblabla.insert .... 
mycollectionsblabla.runCommand('commitTransaction', function(err4, res4){...
```

the problem is, when I am calling that program code very fast several times like 10 times, then its not doing ACID Transactions. And it starts the

```
runCommand('beginTransaction'...
```

in paralell, and of course the

```
runCommand('commitTransaction', ...
```

does fail!!! because it says : transaction already exists, and it also says
no transaction exists to be commited... !!!

You see the problem which is bothering me?
How can I fix that problem to make ACID Transactions?

Do you know any TokuMX driver for nodejs for doing ACID Transactions?

Answer (score 6):

There is a fundamental problem with the way node.js works and the way TokuMX multi-statement transactions work.

In TokuMX, multi-statement transactions (with `beginTransaction`) are associated with the client connection that runs the command.  Any operations done on the same connection after that, until the next `rollbackTransaction` or `commitTransaction` command, count as part of the transaction.

If you start a transaction and some other thread uses your connection, its operations will become part of your transaction.  Also, if you start a thread and then switch to a different connection, those operations after the switch won't be properly associated with a transaction.

The reason we chose this model was that it made sense for the majority of drivers.  With most drivers in languages with explicit threading models, that use connection pooling, there is a driver mechanism to reserve a connection for a given thread of execution, e.g. [start_request in PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/requests.html) or [RequestStart in the MongoDB C# driver](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/d751ceee-e249-f039-120e-fc9c1d440d60.htm).  In these drivers, any thread that wants to use a TokuMX transaction must do so within the context of such a reserved connection.

In node.js, with the current drivers (AFAIK right now) there is no way for a logical group of code to associate itself exclusively with a single transaction.  This is partly because there is not a good concept in the node.js execution model itself of tying a logical group of code together (through multiple callbacks) as a "thread" to which a connection could be associated.  Briefly, there's no way to tell node "execute the `beginTransaction` command, make sure nobody else uses this connection, and when you call my callback, make sure I get a reference to the connection so I can use it for more things".

Now, there is still a set of transactional semantics you can get from TokuMX with the node.js driver if you exclude multi-statement transactions.  All queries still use MVCC snapshots, and all batched inserts, and multi-document updates and deletes are serializably isolated from each other, and are atomic even across multiple documents.  Keep in mind that these are relaxed in a sharded setting; transactional semantics don't cross shard boundaries at this time.

There is a project [BlueRival/node-tokumx-native](https://github.com/BlueRival/node-tokumx-native) by someone who is reportedly working on this problem.  According to [one of their github issues](https://github.com/BlueRival/node-tokumx-native/issues/1) they should be starting work on this problem soon, but I am not in direct contact with them so I can't speak to schedules or planning.

For now, I recommend you try using another driver or try to write your application in such a way that the single-statement transactional semantics of TokuMX are sufficient.

*Disclaimer: I'm a TokuMX engineer.*